# Control/Customize Component name minification in Production React

Tags: reactjs

### Background

I often use "[React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)" to understand the component structure of various website that I like and take inspiration from. Though, lot of websites have random names for the components, few websites have distinguishable names which can be helpful for aspiring React Developers or hobbyists. One such website is https://www.joshwcomeau.com. Below is a screenshot from one of the pages in his website. The name of few of the components explains itself what it is going to render. And since this is his blog, where he talks about various tips and tricks for React Development, it becomes helpful to have a look at this.

### Question

Now when I develop a website using create-react-app(`CRA`), all my component names are minified to a couple of random letters by Webpack. How can I control this behavior?

**Note: My main question is - How to control this behavior in any React application (not just `CRA`). I know that Josh uses Next.js for his blog, so does any framework like Gatsby, Next etc... provide control over this?**.

Note:

- I'm aware that the component names are visible in development mode, but I would like it to be visible in production too (for the reason explained above in "Background").
- I'm aware that webpack can generate "sourcemap" but doing that would expose my entire code structure. So I prefer not to use sourcemaps

| Screenshot of Josh's Website | Screenshot of My Website |
| --- | --- |
| [image: React Devtools from joshwcomeau.com] | [image: React Devtools from my website] |

Comment: You should be minifying in production. If you want to view the component names, check them in development. Also there are sourcemap options which generate sourcemaps but don't include them into the files which allows you to load them when you need to without exposing them to everyone using your website (don't serve them).

Comment: Hello Sir, did you try the `webpack-react-component-name`? would you give me feedback about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a third party library:

From `webpack-react-component-name` [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-react-component-name):

> Normally React component names are minified during compilation. This plugin makes these component names available in production bundles by hooking into Webpack's compilation process, traversing the AST looking for React component definitions and updating the emitted source code to populate the displayName property. This is the property that, when populated, is used by the React Dev Tools extension to determine the name of a component.

So you can install this webpack plugin with:

```
npm install webpack-react-component-name -save-dev
```

once it is installed, add the plugin to the plugins list in webpack configs:

```
  plugins: [
    new WebpackReactComponentNamePlugin()
  ],
```

Comment: Wow, Is that it? and just curious, does this also have any other impact?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure for other impacts but in my opinion, it's just a simple name changer (random name to component name). @Gangula

Comment: Don't forget `const WebpackReactComponentNamePlugin = require('webpack-react-component-name')` at the head of your file. Annoyingly none of the documentation mentions this anywhere.